# Filter and copy using column index

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pick a column in an Excel sheet based on the column index(categoryPoint). I'm then trying to run an advanced filter on this column to select the unique values and copy it into a new sheet using this code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Columns(categoryPoint)).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C2"), _
    Unique:=True
```

It says object or application defined error.

Comment: What is categoryPoint, and if it's a variable what value does it have when the error is thrown? Also, you should fully qualify the `Columns` as well: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(categoryPoint)).AdvancedFilter` in case your ActiveSheet is some other sheet

Comment: The variable holds the value 28. nothing wrong with variable value. Tried fully qualifying as well same error. categoryPoint is an integer Dim

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax (tested):

```
Dim categoryPoint As Long

categoryPoint = 28

Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(categoryPoint).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("C2"), _
    Unique:=True
```

Comment: :( The extract range has a missing or invalid field name it says. Just been stuck on this for so long now

Comment: Yes i did! your code worked fine! thanks! now it's time to assign it to an array!

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark the answer as a reference for others